# firefox fullscreen issue on mac 10.10

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, fullscreen, mozilla

Hi Im developing an application where firefox needs to be kiosk mode on browser start. I got it working on all platforms except mac 10.10 ?
Im compiling mozilla source with "fullscreen" in browser.xul and rkiosk addon and
Using obective-c code to hide dock and top menubar and then start firefox.. Works like charm in all macs but 10.10. In 10.10 it leaves the dockarea and top menu area uncovered.

- Any ideas where i can tweak the mozilla source ?
- Where does mozilla calculate height and width when it starts ?
- Can I tweak the fullscreen api to allow fullscreen from js code rather than on user click ? document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen -- this doesnt work unless a user initiates an event.

Comment: did you tried the [old-lion-fullscreen Add-on](https://github.com/arp/old-lion-fullscreen) ? You can't enable FullScreen API without a user interaction.

Comment: @Kaiido - that is too old. I dont see chrome/content in the firefox source application folder or profile or omni.ja .. im trying to create a dylib with NSApplicationPresentationHideDock, NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar in NSApplicationPresentationOptions

Comment: My bad, didn't noticed it haven't been updated in 3 years... Still works on my 10.9 but it faces the same bug as the one you described. I just tried ff [fullscreen](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ff_fullscreen/) and this one seems to work however